# Pushing selected commit history to github

Tags: git, github, android-source

I'm working on the AOSP project from the local repo that I need to share with the 3rd party. I'm using github for individual projects that I need to share.
At the moment I'm trying to share system/core repo, however I have the problem pushing it to the github. It looks like the repo has a large file in its history that was added and then removed `'libunwindstack/tests/files/offline/jit_debug_x86_32/libartd.so'`

When I try to push the repo including all the previous history, the github generates an error that the file over 100MB cannot be pushed. This is because it is in the history of commits even though it is removed in the most recent commits.

I know there is an option to remove the file completely from the git history using the following command:

```sh
git filter-branch --force --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch <path/filename>" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

, but this is not an option as the local repository is used by many other projects that we run internally under different branches. This might create unnecessary issues.

The question is whether I can commit N latest commits or even only the last commit to the external github repository retaining its hash, so it is not a simple compy and a new commit to that repo? Ideally I'd like to retain the history from 2018 when this file was deleted and keep everything past that point. Would appreciate any pointers with this problem.

Note: the remote github I'm trying to push to is a brand new repo that doesn't have any files/branches in it yet.

Comment: One can push N **earliest commits** but not N **latest** commits because **Git always pushes all commits** from the heads/tags back to the initial commit. To push a chain of N commits one has to create a new branch. In your case you can branch off of a commit before the huge file was added and cherry-pick or rebase all commits after it was deleted. That branch could be pushed. It will be hard to update it in the future but there is no other way.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This is what I was worried about. Basically the filter-branch command will do the same thing, but that creates the problem of updating it in the future. Exactly the same problem.